# calculate percentage contribution of each group based on certain condition SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate the percentage of "Quantity" contribution for 2 groups, group 1 where the "Customer ID" appeared more than once and group 2 where "Customer ID" is once. For example:

```
|ID | OrderID   |Quantity
|---|--------   |-----
|1  |10248      |12
|2  |10248      |10 
|3  |10248      |5 
|4  |10249      |9
|5  |10249      |40
|6  |10250      |10
```

-----Into-----

```
OrderID |Quantity
10248   |27
10249   |49
10250   |10
```

----- Ultimately Into -----

```
Group    % tot Quantity
1         12%   <--- Just OrderID 10250 since it has only 1 order
2         88%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   100.0 * sum(case when cnt = 1  then sumQty else 0 end) / sum(sumQty) as "single Order"
  ,100.0 * sum(case when cnt <> 1 then sumQty else 0 end) / sum(sumQty) as "multiple Orders"
from
 (
    select 
       OrderID
      ,sum(Quantity) as sumQty
      ,count(*) as cnt
    from myTable
    group by OrderId
 ) as dt
```

Comment: The count(*) does the number of order rather by the number of quantity right? I'm thinking more of 10 / (10+49+27) = 12%

Comment: @AndyWang: Ok, fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.Otherwise any wrong please inform me.

```
select a.OrderID,a.grp, Cast(Cast(a.Quantity*100 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(100)) + ' %' as Percentage from (
select OrderID as OrderID,count(OrderID) as grp,Sum(Quantity) as Quantity  from myTable
group by OrderID
) as a
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer doesn't work it replies 33%
This work fine:

```
select 100.0 * sum(case when cnt = 1  then sumQty else 0 end) / sum(sumQty) as 'single Order'
,100.0 * sum(case when cnt <> 1 then sumQty else 0 end) / sum(sumQty) as 'multiple Order'
from
 (
select 
   OrderID
  ,sum(Quantity) as sumQty -- not needed for the final result
  ,count(*) as cnt
from _ds_test_ac
group by OrderId
) as dt
```

If you want in two lines you can do :

```
select cnt = 1 as 'IS Single',   100.0 * sum(sumQty) / tot as 'percent'
from
 (
    select 
       OrderID
      ,sum(Quantity) as sumQty -- not needed for the final result
      ,count(*) as cnt
    from _ds_test_ac
    group by OrderId
 ) as dt join 
 (
 select sum(Quantity) as tot
    from _ds_test_ac
 ) dtot 
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers put the values into a single row, but the OP is asking for two rows.  If this is important:

```
select (case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 2 end) as grp,
       qty / totQty as ratio
from (select OrderID, sum(Quantity) as Qty, count(*) as cnt
      from myTable
      group by OrderId
     ) o cross join
     (select sum(Quantity) as totQty from myTable) x
group by (case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 2 end);
```